# Pandas dataframe to excel comments?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have two `pandas` `dataframes`, `df_chart` and `df_comments`. Both have the same headers and indexes. I was wondering if there was a way to make an excel file with `df_chart` in the cells and `df_comments` in the comments.

From the documentation,

```
df_chart.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name= "Chart")
```

is straightforward enough. However, I can't seem to find anything similar to quickly and efficiently add comments. I was hoping something like:

```
df_comments.to_excel_comments(excel_file, sheet_name= "Chart")
```

may exist, but I think not. Does anyone know of a way I could write this function easily?

Comment: Not with pandas, no. You'll need to work with the underlying Excel-related library, e.g. openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you might approach it.

The code uses `to_excel()` from `Pandas` then opens the workbook with `openpyxl` and iterates through the comments DataFrame to add the comments where applicable.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.comments import Comment

data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
comments = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Comment A1', None], 'B': [None, 'Comment B2']})
excel_path = "result.xlsx"
data.to_excel(excel_path, index=False)

wb = load_workbook(excel_path)
ws = wb.active

for row in comments.iterrows():
    xl_row = row[0] + 2  # +1 for 0-based index, +1 for header
    for xl_col, (col_name, comment_text) in enumerate(row[1].items(), 1):
        if pd.notna(comment_text):  # Check if the comment_text is not NaN
            cell = ws.cell(row=xl_row, column=xl_col)
            # change second arg to a name if you prefer
            cell.comment = Comment(comment_text, "Written by Python process")

wb.save(excel_path)
```